# SonarLint extension in VSCode for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm using SonarLint extension in VSCode to detect warning for C#. I also copied the example in the SonarLint rule to test, but my extension isn't detect any warnings.

[image]

Are there anyone used to SonarLint extension in VSCode to detect warning for C# ? Can you help me to configue it ? Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to the SonarLint team directly via their community forum